# How to communicate with IoT device from webhook using rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, eventmachine, google-home

I am learning [Google Home Integration](https://developers.google.com/actions/smarthome/) with IoT device. I have IoT device which reponds only TCP/WS protocol to get/update things in the device. I am running webhook in rails application. Rails web service can get request from google assistant and respond back. Now to fullfill the request received from google assistant, I have to make TCP/WS request to the device. I am running client web socket program in the device to get request. server web socket program is in server side. [my problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5335445/persistent-tcp-connection-in-rails-app) (same) is how to forward received request from google assistant to the device using web socket and get response from device and forward to google assistant.

Here is sample controller code.

```
class WebhookController < ApplicationController
  def create
    value = params[:result][:parameters][:value].first
    action = params[:result][:parameters]['action'].first
    /*
       Here I have to access the following web socket connection and send the request and need to get response back and update to google assistant.
    */
    res = { 'speech' => "temperature #{value} successfully changed.", 'displayText' => 'success' }
    render json: res
  end
end
```

Sample web socket server which is already connected with client which is running in the device.

```
require 'em-websocket'

EM.run {
  EM::WebSocket.run(:host => "0.0.0.0", :port => 8080) do |ws|
    ws.onopen { |handshake|
      puts "WebSocket connection open"
      ws.send "Hello Client, you connected to #{handshake.path}"
    }

    ws.onclose { puts "Connection closed" }

    ws.onmessage { |msg|
      puts "Recieved message: #{msg}"
      ws.send msg
      /*
           Here It should get msg from controller and forward to the client and get response from client and send to server controller.
      */
    }

  end
}
```